# MenuItem databinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, contextmenu, menuitem

I've been puzzling over this for a day or so with no luck - I'm probably missing something obvious. Basically, I have a context menu with two items. One is statically declared, and bound to a command. The other has no command of its own, but binds to a collection of viewmodels. So visually the menu should look something like:

- Delete
- Add

  - Item 1
  - Item 2

Where the items vary depending on the thing the context menu was bound to. Originally I had something like this:

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="itemContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="_Delete"
                  Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Add" DataContext=""
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTypes}">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=ItemType.Name}"
                              Command="{Binding Path=AddItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
```

Which works, but gives me the nested MenuItems others have experienced. Based on a couple threads here on stackoverflow, I then tried this:

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="itemContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="_Delete"
                  Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Add" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTypes}">
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">                        
                    <Setter Property="Header"
                            Value="{Binding Path=ItemType.Name}" />
                    <Setter Property="Command"
                            Value="{Binding Path=AddItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}" />
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
                            Value="{Binding}" />
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
```

However, when I do that my bindings all fail with errors like:

> BindingExpression path error: 'ItemType' property not found on 'object' ''String'
>
> BindingExpression path error: 'AddItemCommand' property not found on 'object' ''Grid'

To me that says that the DataContext is getting lost when I use the ItemContainerStyle. What am I missing?

**edit:**

I think I had some red herrings in here, so I've simplified the examples further to try and narrow down the problem.

Working but screwy layout-wise:

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="itemContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="_Delete" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Add" DataContext=""
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTypes}">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=ItemType.Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
```

Non-working with a BindingExpression error:

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="itemContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="_Delete" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Add" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTypes}">
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">                        
                    <Setter Property="Header"
                            Value="{Binding Path=ItemType.Name}" />
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
```

Comment: you didn't state your desired result.

Comment: The desired result is to have the contents of the AvailableTypes collection (on the DataContext of the parent MenuItem) render as child MenuItems, but without the visual artifacts my original solution introduced. Sorry, I thought that was clearer.

Comment: All this code does not add up, in your first example there already should have been binding errors as you can forget about using `RelativeSource` from inside the `ContextMenu`. Also the targeted `Grid` hardly has a command-property on it.

Comment: Sorry, in the first example that should be DataContext.AddItemCommand. But yes, it does work like a champ, except for the layout issue. Obviously the rules are different using the ItemTemplate vs the ItemContainerStyle, and therein lies my confusion. How do I bind to the templated items from the ItemsSource when using the ItemContainerStyle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in 3.5. I upgraded my project to 4.0, and now everything works as expected.